# When I use .value to get an input value it returns Undefined

Tags: javascript, html, css

When ever I get the value of a text input using .value, then display it on a web page it displays Undefined.

I have viewed many fixes and none worked.

Java Script

```
function user() {
    let userNum = 1;
    let userSays = document.getElementsByClassName("text_box").value;
    let x = document.createElement("P");
    let y = document.getElementById("chat_box");
    x.setAttribute("class", "chatUser");
    x.setAttribute("id", 'u'+ userNum);
    x.innerHTML = "@User:" + userSays;
    y.appendChild(x);
    userNum += 1;
    updateScroll()
}
```

HTML

```
</div>

<input class = "text_box" type="text" placeholder="This does something">
<button id = inputPrint onclick= 'user()'>User</button>
```

When the person on the page types something in the input box, then hits the User button, it should display. User: *What user typed*

However it currently displays.  User: *Undefined*

Comment: `.getElementsByClassName()` returns a **list** of elements, even if there's only one matching element on the page. You have to iterate through the elements of the list and operate on each one individually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName()` returns collection. You have to use specific index.

Change

```
let userSays = document.getElementsByClassName("text_box").value;
```

To

```
let userSays = document.getElementsByClassName("text_box")[0].value;
```

Comment: Thank you, That fixed the problem

Comment: @Acelib25, you are most welcome :)